# Adobe XD CC 2020 get error when install

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I try to install Adobe XD CC 2020 in windows 10 2017 but get error such as this image :

[image]

Comment: Update Windows 10 to 1803+

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 versions below 1803 are not supported.

[image]

You can double-check this by typing `winver` in the search bar, but a copyright date of 2017 would suggest you are still on an older, unsupported version.

[image]

Your fix is to update Windows.